# Getting empty buckets array in elasticsearch aggregation

Tags: elasticsearch

I'm using version 5.4.1 of ElasticSearch.

When I try to perform a groupBy aggregate/bucket aggregate, I'm not getting any values in the bucket array.

This is my index:

```
   curl -X PUT localhost:9200/urldata -d '{
    "mappings" : {
        "components" : {
            "properties" : {
                "name" : {
                    "type" : "keyword",
                    "index" : "not_analyzed"
                },
                "status" : {
                    "type" : "keyword",
                    "index" : "not_analyzed"
                },
                "timestamp":{
                    "type":"date",
                    "index":"not_analyzed"
                }
            }
        }
    }
}'
```

And this the aggregate query:

```
curl -XGET 'localhost:9200/urldata/_search?pretty' -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -d'
    {
      "size": 0,
      "aggs": {
        "components": {
          "terms": {
            "field": "name.keyword"
          }
        }
      }
    }
    '
```

Output:

```
{  
"took":2,
   "timed_out":false,
   "_shards":{  
      "total":5,
      "successful":5,
      "failed":0
   },
   "hits":{  
      "total":3,
      "max_score":0.0,
      "hits":[  

      ]
   },
   "aggregations":{  
      "components":{  
         "doc_count_error_upper_bound":0,
         "sum_other_doc_count":0,
         "buckets":[  

         ]
      }
   }
}
```

Where am I going wrong??

Comment: Can you provide some document example?

Comment: {name: "A", status: "success", created_at: "2017-08-17" }
{name: "A",status: "failure",created_at: "2017-08-18"}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this, it should do it:

```
{
  "size": 0,
  "aggs": {
    "components": {
      "terms": {
        "field": "name"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

**EDIT:**

Here is all the steps to replicate your use case:

```
PUT test
{
    "settings" : {
        "index" : {
            "number_of_shards" : 1, 
            "number_of_replicas" : 0
        }
    }
}

PUT test/_mapping/people_name
{  
  "properties":{  
      "name":{  
        "type":"keyword",
        "index":"not_analyzed"
      },
      "status":{  
        "type":"keyword",
        "index":"not_analyzed"
      },
      "timestamp":{  
         "type":"date",
         "index":"not_analyzed"
      }
  }
}

POST test/people_name
{
  "name": "A", 
  "status": "success", 
  "created_at": "2017-08-17"
}

POST test/people_name
{
  "name": "A", 
  "status": "success_2", 
  "created_at": "2017-06-15"
}

POST test/people_name
{
  "name": "B", 
  "status": "success", 
  "created_at": "2017-09-15"
}

GET test/people_name/_search
{
  "size": 0,
  "aggs": {
    "components": {
      "terms": {
        "field": "name"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

The result of the aggregation is:

```
{
  "took": 3,
  "timed_out": false,
  "_shards": {
    "total": 1,
    "successful": 1,
    "failed": 0
  },
  "hits": {
    "total": 3,
    "max_score": 0,
    "hits": []
  },
  "aggregations": {
    "components": {
      "doc_count_error_upper_bound": 0,
      "sum_other_doc_count": 0,
      "buckets": [
        {
          "key": "A",
          "doc_count": 2
        },
        {
          "key": "B",
          "doc_count": 1
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Tried this but it threw the exception:  {"error":{"root_cause":[{"type":"illegal_argument_exception","reason":"Fielddata is disabled on text fields by default. .                                                                          Then I set fielddata=true and now it's working.Can't understand how can ES documentation can be so buggy.Atleast they should have mentioned this issue.

Comment: Which exception? Which version are you on?

Comment: I'm using ES version 5.4.1

Comment: So it's good? I just use your mapping. I had no problem going my query.

Comment: Yes.Well the document tells to use "name.keyword" which doesn't seem to work.Your query works but you need to set fielddata=true and if the type is 'keyword' you don't need to set this (fielddata=true) according to a comment on ES blog regarding a similar issue. And this clearly failed to work.Then I set fielddata=true (which I shouldn't have done according to my mapping) which worked for me.

Comment: No. You misunderstood the documentation. They state that you should use `name.keyword` only if in your mapping `name`is a `text` and you have another field `name.keyword` of type `keyword`. The query you write in your question should be `name` and not `name.keyword` according to your mapping. On my part I used your mapping and didn't have to set the field data to true. I will update my answer with all the steps